# want to call textfield data of action performed to another java class

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to get `JTextfield` data of action perfomed of (main page) class to other java class.

Comment: Use Accessors and Mutators.

Comment: What do you actually try to do, it isn't clear from your post? Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why is there `view_data` and a `View_data` class? Are you trying to confuse yourself?

Comment: sorry...it is only one class View_data....and i want data of textfield PO_number in View_data class

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `String` to a constructor of `View_Data`

```
public class View_Data {
    private String text;

    public View_Data(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    PO_number number =jTextField1.getText();

    View_data vd = new View_data(number);
}
```

Or you can use a setter

```
public class View_Data {
    private String text;

    public View_Data() {
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    PO_number number =jTextField1.getText();

    View_data vd = new View_data();
    vd.setText(number);
}
```

---

Also, you may want to make `View_Data vd` globally scoped in the Main class, if you want to use it else where in the program.

Also, I don't see the point of having two `main` methods. I don't think you need the `main` in the `View_Data` if there is already one in the Main class the program is running from.